# How can I make an image full width inside a paragraph which is 70% (text)

Tags: images

Got this small riddle:
How can I make an image inside the_content() be full width, when it is inside a content paragraph which is `70% width`.
I've look around and I don't seem to find the answer.
I tried making the img absolute positioned `right:0 left:0`, but i cannot clear it and next paragraph goes underneath, since you cannot clear an absolute positioned element like you do with floated elements.
I don't rule out a JS solution, but whatever it is I need little direction because I'm pretty lost at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, JS with jQuery width(), removeAttr() to avoid wordpress inline width and height. Also negative margins.

```
 var anchoArticulo = $('article.single-post').width();
    $('article.single-post div.single-post img.ancho_completo')
    .removeAttr('width height')
    .css('margin-left' , -(winWidth - anchoArticulo)/2)
    .css('width' , winWidth);
```

Class `ancho_completo` is added in dashboard to the image.

Comment: please accept your answer... anyway, not sure you could not do the same with plain CSS. One of the problems with you code is that it does not handle window size change.

Comment: Yes it does, if you place it inside and outside the $(window).resize(function(){}); To accept my own answer i have to wait.